# There is already an object named ##Temp2 in the database

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a global Temporary table and I intend to have so as I want multiple connections to be able to access it.

I am using something kind of SQL server agents to employ parallelism and so multiple connections are established while the script is executing.

I have a procedure called `dbo.Outputprocedure` where the execution starts and ends. Multiple procedures are called from here which are executed in different connections.

Now , my problem is that I delete `##Temp2` table both at starting of `dbo.Output Procedure` and at the end.
However, it does not look like it gets deleted.

Here is the query that I use to delete `##Temp2` before I create.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..dbo.##Temp2') Is not null
Begin
drop table ##Temp2
End

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..dbo.##Temp2') Is null
Begin
create table ##Temp2
(
Rownumber int not null,
--ValFromUser nvarchar(30),
--ColumnName nvarchar(30),
--ValFromFunc decimal(18, 4),
--FuncWeight decimal(18, 4),
Percentage decimal(18, 4) not null,

);

  /*some code*/

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..dbo.##Temp2') Is not null
Begin
PRINT 'DROPPED' -- not printed
DROP TABLE ##Temp2  
End 


 End
```

Since 'DROPPED' is not printed, it clearly means table does not get deleted, but why is that ? I am not dropping table anywhere else. Besides, I do not get this error :

```
There is already an object named ##Temp2 in the database
```

if I drop the table before starting to execute it. What exactly may be the problem and what I may do to resolve the issue ?

Comment: `tempdb..dbo.##Temp2'` should be `tempdb.dbo.##Temp2'`

Comment: What happens if you remove the `dbo`, i.e., `IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##Temp2')` ?  And @MartinSmith, the `..` is correct

Comment: Global temp tables should be avoided in general as you will have lots of concurrency issues. Even worse in your case because you are expecting lots of people hitting this same stuff at the same time.

Comment: @Tom - No - it is only "correct" if you don't specify the schema. And even then it is best to just specify the schema.

Comment: @Tom no it is not. `Database.schema.object` What he has is `database..schema.object`.

Comment: @tom, no it is not. You then have a four-part name making tempdb a server not a database. I took out the extra period as Martin suggested and the drop table worked just fine.

Comment: @Tom, no it is not... got it

Comment: @Tom GIVE IT A TRY!!!

Comment: I'm with Sean Lange on this one. Why use a temporary table? it seems like a recipe for trouble.

Comment: replacing tempdb..##Temp2 with tempdb.#Temp2 worked :) Thank you.

Comment: Creating global temp tables with a generic name (##Temp2) and also having logic that drops it if it exists is a good practice if you want to create strange problems later...

Comment: Could be.  I would like to know what problems I may come across and why is it such a bad practice .Replacing the generic name is not a problem but why dropping it if it exists should not be there ?